# Navigation text center not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm having an issue with a site I'm currently working on. I have a logo and navigation within a header element with the navigation's ul text centered. This works perfect in Chrome but not Firefox. I've seen some people suggesting `text-align: -moz-center;` but this doesn't seem to be working for me. Any suggestions?

Thanks

http://mmwebco.co.uk

Comment: try -moz-text-align:center;

Comment: Doesn't work I'm afraid

Comment: I highly suggest you re-write the navigation bar using inline-blocks, or at least floats. The way you're trying to manipulate display: table just for vertical alignment that can be achieved using `line-height: 8em;' is overkill and is what is causing you these issues.

Comment: Okay, I'll get to it, thanks

Comment: You're right. I removed the table and used inline-block with line height. I don't know how I would add you comment as the answer but if you copy it as a answer, I'll give it the tick.